# Unable to Find File Field "photo" when it exists explicitly on the page? Rails 4, Minimagick, Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, minimagick

I am using Carrierwave and Minimagick for image uploads to a user's profile photo. I have followed the directions on [Carrierwave's readme](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) of how to create an uploader and mount it. I am testing with Rspec and Capybara.

Here is my user_profile_spec.rb, relevant lines:

```
feature 'Visitor views profile page' do
    before(:each) do
        @user = sign_in
        click_link "Profile"
    end

    scenario 'can upload a photo' do
        attach_file 'photo', File.join(Rails.root, 'public', 'images', 'default.png')
        click_button "Update Profile"
        expect(page).to have_content "default.png" 
    end
```

Here is my _form.html.erb for the user profile edit page:

```
<%= form_for @profile, url: @profile, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>

    <strong>Photo:</strong>
      <%= image_tag @profile.photo.display if @profile.photo? %>
    </p>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :photo %>
      <%= f.file_field :photo %>
    ....
<% end %>
```

And my error:

```
  1) Visitor views profile page can upload a photo
 Failure/Error: attach_file 'photo', File.join(Rails.root, 'public', 'images', 'default.png')
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find file field "photo"
 # ./spec/features/profiles/user_profile_spec.rb:35:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have tried changing the attach_file part to `:photo`, changing the file attached, using my Factorygirl profile model which has a photo already uploaded:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :profile do
    website 'http://www.validwebsite.com'
    country 'Valid country'
    about 'Valid about statements that go on and on'
    profession 'Validprofession'
    age 22
    user
    photo { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'support', 'profile_photos', 'default.png')) }
```

end
end

Couldn't sort out the error. Is it a glitch with carrierwave?

Here is my photo_uploader.rb, don't think its necessary but just in case, all the information.

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def default_url
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("images/" + [version_name,     "default.png"].compact.join('_'))

    "/images/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  end

  version :display do
    process :resize_to_fill => [150, 150]
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [50, 50]
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

end
```

**Edit:**  Added some new information about the spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current spec, [attach_file](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#attach_file-instance_method) is looking for an id, name or label matching "photo", which you apparently don't have. Any of these should work, instead:

```
attach_file 'profile[photo]', File.join(Rails.root, 'public', 'images', 'default.png') # name
attach_file 'profile_photo', File.join(Rails.root, 'public', 'images', 'default.png') # id
attach_file 'Photo', File.join(Rails.root, 'public', 'images', 'default.png') # label
```